# What is the correct way to check for the existence of a nested attribute in Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

There are multiple ways to check for the existence of a nested attribute in chef, and I'm not sure which is correct/best, and if any will result in empty attributes being stored on the node:

```rb
node[:parent] and node[:parent][:child]

node.attribute?(:parent) and node[:parent].attribute?(:child))

node[:parent].nil? and node[:parent][:child].nil?
```

It'd be greatly preferred to be able to check for the parent and child at the same time, but I don't know if that's possible. I am using Chef 10, not Chef 11, though answers explaining either are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct "modern" way to do this is to use the `exist?()` helper:

```
if node.exist?('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
  # do stuff with node['foo']['bar']['baz']
end
```

This supersedes the old chef-sugar `deep_fetch` mechanism and has been built into chef-client for a very long time at this point.

There is also a `read()` helper to get the value out, which will return nil if any intermediate key does not exist:

```
fizz = node.read('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

It is identical to the Hash#dig method which was later added to ruby which is also supported as an alias:

```
fizz = node.dig('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Answer (score 15):

Node attribute object is HashMap. You can use ruby native API to lookup nested attributes.

Chef Node Object provides a number of helper methods like:

```
node.attribute?()
node[:foo].attribute?(:bar)
node[:foo].member?(:bar)
```

There is also a new method `node.debug_value()` in chef 11 to help you debug node attributes which is also helpful:

```
node.debug_value(:foo, :bar)
```

Details can be found from the article [Chef 11 In-Depth: Attributes Changes](http://www.opscode.com/blog/2013/02/05/chef-11-in-depth-attributes-changes/)

Answer (score 5):

The way I've solved this more recently has been to always set default values for attributes used in a cookbook where possible.

For example, `cookbook/attributes/default.rb` would contain:

```
default[:parent][:child] = nil
```

And the in the recipe, any check for the attributes value can be reduced to:

```
node[:parent][:child].nil?
```

Of course, it's usually far more useful to have a usable default value and to not have to check at all.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the chef-sugar cookbook [`deep_fetch`](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-sugar#node) extension that allows for safe references to deep attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I found a really elegant solution [here](http://blog.hartshorne.net/2013/07/using-attributes-that-might-not-exist.html) that uses `rescue NoMethodError` at the end of the `if` conditional.

```
if node['foo']['bar']['baz']
   do the stuff I want
end rescue NoMethodError
```

Comment: That will also rescue any NoMethodError caused by any other clause added to the conditional (so under extension to `if node['foo']['bar']['baz'] && shoulddoit?` will gobble up any programming errors in `def shoulddoit?` that raise NoMethodError).  And it will also rescue any NoMethodError raised by the "do the stuff i want" block.  For the absolutely trivial case this works, but once the trivial case becomes complicated this greatly hinders the ability to debug anything.  This solution should not be used.

Comment: In that linked web page if the author had typo'd `include_recipie "ganglia::default"` (extra i in recipe, which is a reasonably common typo) then the rescue swallows the error about the typo.